# I cannot clone a GitHub repo in Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, devops, cloning

As you can see in the image when trying to put my repo in the Source Code Management I got an error

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: git ls-remote -h.

I have the git and github plugins installed

[image]

Comment: I formatted your words so we can actually read them. For future reference, don't put everything inside the link text.

Comment: Also, try googling the error message. I found another question on stack overflow with a similar screenshot and an answer.

Comment: Oh man thank you I googled it first but i did not fine anything related you are better than me googling. Thanks for help it worked